# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'USERS' does not exist

Tags: eclipse, derby

I have written as small code for standalone application where user can enter username and password to login. Application is designed to fetch these login details from USERS table COOP database.
Everything working properly when I run this in Eclipse. But when I run jar file of this project I got this message:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'USERS' does not exist.
Please help  to resolve this problem.
I am using apache derby.
below is the code:

```
                String txtUsername = txtUserName.getText();
                char[] password = passPassword.getPassword();
                String txtPassword = new String(password);
                
                try {
                    Class.forName(DRIVER);
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
                    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from USERS");                        
            
                    while(resultset.next()) {
                        if(resultset.getString(4).toString().equals(txtUsername) && resultset.getString(5).toString().equals(txtPassword)) {
                            homePage home = new homePage();
                            setVisible(false);
                            home.setVisible(true);
                        }
                        else {
                            
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Username or Password.","Invalid Credentials",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }                   
                    //if(statement != null) statement.close();
                    if(conn != null) conn.close();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: You're probably not using the same database. What is "JDBC_URL" in your program? See if this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55926984/193453

Comment: JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:COOP;create=true"

Comment: Probably you have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36089205/193453